# Generic Resource Adapter genericra.rar not found in Glassfish 3.1

Tags: java, glassfish, jms, activemq-classic, generic-jms-ra

I have started configuring `ApacheMQ` `JMS` Provider in `Glassfish` 3.1 server. I was following the steps mentioned in http://www.scribd.com/doc/24613711/GlassFish-Administration-Sample-Chapter

I could run and create resource-adapter-config object using the `asadmin` command. Next step is to deploy the `genericra.rar` in app server. But I am not able to find any file named `genericra.rar` in glassfish server.

Reference path given in document was from lib/addon/resourceadapters.... But i dont see any folder by name addon in glassfish.

May be it is very silly, but I am not able to found and proceed. Kindly help me what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to manually download the genericjms resource adapter and deploy it. Hope it helps to some newbie...

Comment: Where can I get the generic jms ra from?

Comment: The source code is in this GitHub repo [genericmessagingra](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/genericmessagingra).